# Dense subset of the plane

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a sequence $x_n\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\subset \{x_n\}$. Let $r_n\in \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of real numbers with $r_n>0$, $\sum_n r_n=1$ and $U=\bigcup_n B(x_n,r_n)$ (where $B(x,r)$ the open ball at $x$ of radius $r$ in the plane).

I want to show that $U$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The set $U$ is dense because $U\supset \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$?
Also how to show that no straight line is contained in $U$?

Comment: $U$ is dense because $U\supset \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ indeed. But that implies $\operatorname{diam}(U) \geqslant \operatorname{diam}(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}) = +\infty$. Did you mean measure, perhaps, instead of diameter?

Comment: @DanielFischer It can't be measure, since it would then be $\sum \pi r_i^2$. I think he is using some odd definition of "diameter."

Comment: The intersection of $U$ with any line consists of chords of the balls $B(x_n,r_n)$, and the total length of all these chords is at most 2.